# How to select raster bands and layer features intersects with another layer?

Tags: pyqgis, qgis-3

I want to get raster bands from raster layer and layer features from vector layer if they intersect with another vector layer.

[image]

vector2 my main layer. If vector1 features in vector2 layer it should be selected (in this example all of them should be selected) and if raster cells in vector2 it's cell values should return.

I investigate [this](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/168266/pyqgis-a-geometry-intersectsb-geometry-wouldnt-find-any-intersections) example but it did not work for me.